# Qlabel under layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qwidget, qlabel

I would like  to do something like the picture I post just below:
[image]

Basically, I would like to show a vertical layout over one Qlabel for rendering a camera stream in that QLabel, and the buttons in my vertical layout are shown with the video under.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you put a camera stream on a QLabel? Just use a QCameraViewFinder widget, see [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html).

Then, even using the QtCreator designer, you can put anything you want over the camera widget.

Just remember to call *yourwidget->raise()* to keep it visible.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that solution. You have understood just I wanted. :)