# Use a QCameraViewFinder object in similar way as QLabel

Tags: qt, qimage, qlabel

I would like to use a QCameraViewFinder for displaying QImages or Pixmaps images.

If I use a QLabel object, I can set easily the images with its method "setPixmap", but how could I use a QCameraViewFinder in a similar way??

Thanks!!

Comment: The `Qt` documentation contains an [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html) of what you want.

Comment: QCameraViewFinder is a specialized class to show the data acquired through QCamera, why do you want to show QImage or similar? What advantages do you think you have in comparison to the use of QLabel?

Comment: Basically, you can put over the QCameraViewFinder buttons or what you want and show under that buttons the images..... With QLabel you can not do it...

Comment: Like this @eyllanesc : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330412/qlabel-under-layout/48337854#48337854

Comment: @Arritmic The answer has given you an example, then from what you have tried :D